# OneNote link won't resolve to correct page

Tags: onenote

I created a document folder content type in sharepoint 2010 that has a Status link field. I try and populate it with a link to a OneNote page, and instead of linking to the page it links to a "New Section 1" Untitle page in the root of the OneNote location. I copy and pasted the URL itself into the browser, and it resolves correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: the link is this:  https://portal2010.amazon.com/sites/FLASH/_layouts/OneNote.aspx?id=%2fsites%2fFLASH%2fProject%20Library%2fProject%20Status&wd=target%28China%2fWeChat%2fPRJ.14.03213.one%7c7C896C58-E71A-44B1-A1B6-4E83DA6DDEEF%2fStatus%7cCB5DDB57-1325-429F-8520-B4FBD120E043

Comment: I shortened it using bit.ly but it still gives root of onenote file.